# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in mysqlDb python

Tags: python, python-2.4

I am trying to test the following with python but I get the invalid syntax error:

```
db = None

try:

db = mdb.connect("localhost","user","pass","dbName") 

with db:

    cur = db.cursor()                   
    cur.execute("SELECT * from product")

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print row

except mdb.Error, e:

print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
sys.exit(1)
```

The error is the following:

```
  File "script.py", line 11
with db:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please include the `SyntaxError` and format the first couple of lines of your code exactly as you have them in your script?

Comment: Please reformat your question.

Comment: Except for the indentation everthing _seems_ to be ok. Are you sure that you are using python 2.7?

Comment: actually not. I am using python 2.4 apparently

Comment: Well the `with` statement is available from python 2.5+. That's pretty much why it will never work. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be nice to see all your imports declarations too to see what could be missing from your code.  I assume that you at least have the import MySQLdb somewhere.  I made a dummy database with a couple of data rows to test this out.  Not sure how python let you get away with the indentation blocks being all messed up, but maybe it's just your code indentation posting error on here.

This is the code I tried and seemed to have no issues:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

db = None

try:

    db = mdb.connect("localhost","user", "password", "test_data")

    ## with db:  ## try taking this out for Python 2.4
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print row

except mdb.Error, e:

    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Just saw your last comment.  If you are using Python 2.4, try taking out the "with db:"  line.